# PSPICE errors when capacitors are 0Farads

Tags: simulation, spice

I'm getting a `value may not be zero` error wheneever I try to simulate a circuit containing capacitors whose values are zero.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm taking measurements by increasing capacitance in the circuit from zero.

Comment: Start at ~0.00000001. You're dividing by zero. The math no longer works.

Comment: @Connor: please make that an answer so this Q doesn't live on on eternally in the *unanswered questions* list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the equation for the impedance of a capacitor:

$$Z_C = \dfrac{1}{j\omega C} $$

Now, division by zero is undefined so *setting the capacitance C=0 should cause the circuit simulator to complain*.

In addition, in the time domain, voltage across a capacitor is proportional to the time integral of the current.  What is the constant of proportionality?

$$\dfrac{1}{C} $$

Once again, division by zero results by setting C=0.

*Conceptually* though, a capacitor with zero capacitance is effectively an open circuit.